# Consulta, guardar informacion de la app (en kotlin)

Tags: kotlin

Estoy desarrollando una app que guarda informacion ( no importa que tipo de informacion ).
Ya tengo casi todo terminado pero al ser nuevo en programar apps, no tengo mucho conocimiento en como guardar la informacion de tal manera que cuando inicie sesion en otro dispositivo e instale la app me descargue los datos que tenia en el otro dispositivo
Ejemplo: Tengo instalada la APP en mi "dispositivo_1" y guardo la informacion "X" y quiero que al instalar la APP en otro dispositivo (dispositivo_2), se me descarge la informacion "X" (que ya habia guardado en el dispositivo_1), pero si alguna otra persona instala la APP en su dispositivo (dispositivo_3), que no se descargue la informacion "X", que tenga su propia informacion que descargar (si es que la hay)
Que recomienda que investigue y utilice ?.
Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿No estas usando un base de datos para tu app? porque con una base de datos ahí podrías almacenar los datos ya sean los usuarios u otras cosas, el más común que yo sepa sería firebase, investiga sobre firebase y ve si te podría funcionar

Comment: No termino de entender bien la pregunta, pues lo primero es, ¿Qué información quieres guardar? ¿Qué datos quieres descargar? Por lo menos, vi dos interrogantes.

Comment: Como subraya @FranqoBalsamo, la pregunta no es clara. Si se trata de contraseñas para inicio de sesión, podrías usar [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth?hl=es-419). Eso es una cosa. Otra **muy distinta** sería la **persistencia  de datos**. Para ello puedes usar Room, o Firebase, o ambos ... depende. Y otra cosa sería tener datos **sincronizados**. Si lo quieres en tiempo real, Firebase es lo mejor y más simple, pero para muchos usuarios / datos tendrías que pasar por caja. Puedes sincronizar también entre Room y una BD remota usando Workmanager.

Comment: Mil disculpas por no expresarme mejor, ahi trate de editar la pregunta para que quede mas clara, Gracias